# Android webserver : how to know the request method received (GET or POST)

Tags: android, http, post, get, handler

In my class DeviceHandler I want to know the HTTP request method used; I don't understand how with my HttpRequest object ?

```
public class DeviceHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

...

public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
                        HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException,
                                                IOException {

// I want to dispatch the treatment according GET or POST request received from my client
```

Thank you guys !

Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html

use

RequestLine rl = request.getRequestLine();

to retrieve RequestLine instance, then you can call

String m = rl.getMethod();

to get method of request.

Comment: Thanks Dario ! Do you know how can I retrieve my data received (in case of POST request) in my method void handle(...) ? From my client, I post JSON data and I want to retrieve here.

Comment: Probably request is instance of HttpEntityEnclosingRequest. So check it with instance of and cast it, then you can call .getEntity() to get HttpEntity. Then use String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);